# How to enqueue only specific script's/style's in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I want to improve the performance of my website by disabling/deregister unnecessary script/style.
I want to enqueue only specific script/style in my whole website, regardless of page, Custom Post Type.

I know there is a plugin(`Asset CleanUp: Page Speed Booster`) to do this job,
but I want to do this from the Code level.

Thank You!

Comment: Are the scripts/CSS files you're talking about all yours, or are you talking about preventing other plugins' or theme assets from loading?

Comment: actually i want to enqueue selected/specific scripts/style which could be my own or from other plugins